# How to make responsive two overlapping columns

Tags: css, html

Hi guys can you help me how to create a the design I made in Photoshop. I actually used col-md-6 to make it two columns. but the problem is that making on div height is bit taller than the other. Here is the image I am talking about [image]

```
<div class="col-md-6" class="white">
     <h1>LOGISTIC</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" class="ship">   
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" class="black">
     <h1>DELIVERY</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" class="pipe">    
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" class="white">
     <h1>STORAGE</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" class="tank">
</div>
```

css

```
.ship{
background: url(../img/resources/ship.png);
}

.tank{
background: url(../img/resources/tank.png);
}

.pipe{
background: url(../img/resources/pipe.png);
}
```

Please Help I am stock here, thanks in advance

Comment: Please include all 3 images that you are referring to in your css. The height of those images is going to impact the height of your divs.

Comment: @AdamScharp yes I actually forgot to add no its been edited, sorry.

Comment: That is a single image. Please include ship.png, tank.png, and pipe.png as separate images. If those image urls are a public resource, maybe just specify the full url in your css (for this example).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you specify the `height` in all your classes below:

```
.ship{
     height: /*set the height of ship.png*/
     background-image: url(../img/resources/ship.png);
}

.tank{
     height: /*set the height of tank.png*/
     background-image: url(../img/resources/tank.png);
}

.pipe{
     height: /*set the height of pipe.png*/
     background-image: url(../img/resources/pipe.png);
}
```